# Remove other linux installation on same hard disk

Tags: ubuntu, arch-linux, grub2

I have the following setup:

```
[phil@thinkpad ~]$ lsblk 
NAME   MAJ:MIN RM   SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT
sda      8:0    0 238,5G  0 disk 
├─sda1   8:1    0  52,3G  0 part 
├─sda2   8:2    0 111,8G  0 part /home
├─sda3   8:3    0   954M  0 part [SWAP]
└─sda4   8:4    0    50G  0 part /
sr0     11:0    1  1024M  0 rom
```

where :

```
sda1 : root partition of ubuntu
sda2 : home partition of ubuntu & arch
sda3 : swap partition of ubuntu & arch
sda4 : root partition of arch
```

what i want to achieve :
delete the ubuntu root partition (sda1)

what is my problem / fear :
when i boot up, GRUB is displayed to choose from either arch or ubuntu. This is the grub installation from ubuntu, so if i delete the ubuntu root partition (sda1), the grub installation is also gone, right?

-> How can I overwrite the (ubuntu) grub installation with the other (arch) grub installation?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you delete the Ubuntu root, the bootloader will still be in MBR of the harddrive, **but** probably will only produce errors, because it invokes files from /boot on the partition from which it was installed.

I would suggest you boot into Arch, delete the Ubuntu partition and install grub anew via

```
sudo grub-install /dev/sda 
sudo grub-mkconfig -o /boot/grub/grub.cfg
```

The first command installs the first stage of the bootloader into the MBR and the second will create an appropriate config-file derived from /etc/default/grub and /etc/grub.d/

For further info on how to install Grub under ArchLinux see
[Archwiki:Grub](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Grub)

Answer (score 0):

In addition to nephente's answer I suggest as a general decision to create a small partition (50 MiB) which is used for Grub (or whatever) only.

Your Linux installations get configured so that they don't touch the MBR but their `/boot` partition (which may be `/` as in your case) only.

The result is a two-stage boot loader: The first one "cannot" break. And if one of the stage 2 loaders breaks then you can still boot the other system.